# Multi-Column Vertical Scrolling in CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Presently, is there a way to do multi-column scrolling in CSS or CSS with JavaScript?

To describe what I mean by this, I've set up a quick demo on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/S7AGp/

When too much text is in the div, I would like to be able to scroll vertically, with new text coming up from bottom of the right-most column, and the old text exiting above the left most column - Basically, like a text-area, except with two columns.

Instead, what happens is that it creates extra columns you have to to scroll horizontally for.

While I could try to store each line of text in an array, and then change that on scroll, I was curious if there is already a way to do this in plain CSS or if a solution already exists via JavaScript. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

CSS Columns with vertical scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/MmLQL/3/

HTML

```
    <div runat="server" id="div_scroll">
       <div runat="server" id="div_columns">
          <p> Some text ...</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #div_scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 1060px; /*modify to suit*/
    height: 340px; /*modify to suit*/
    }

    #div_columns
    {
    direction:ltr; /*column direction ltr or rtl - modify to suit*/
    columns: 3; /*number of columns - modify to suit*/
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 1000px; /*width of columns div has to be specified - modify to suit*/
    /* do not specify height parameter as it has to be unrestricted*/
    padding: 20px;  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about somthing like css regions: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/diving-into-css-regions/

**HTML:**

```
<p class="example-text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."</p>

<div class="regions"></div>
<div class="regions"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.example-text {
  -webkit-flow-into: example-text-flow;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.regions {
   -webkit-flow-from: example-text-flow;
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 2px;
   margin: 5px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

They support is limited right now to webkit:
http://caniuse.com/css-regions

Unfortunatally I don't know of any fallback or replacement.

Comment: That seems very interesting and I will look into it. That said, it doesn't seem to allow for native scrolling. I might be able to use the JavaScript API once it is more supported to emulate what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you though!

Comment: CSS Regions would be an ideal candidate for this problem. However development is still in progress on the feature. A slow and painful solution would be to break your text with JavaScript and do layout yourself. Do some thinking if that effort makes sense for your use case. There be dragons out there.

Answer (score 0):

Bad:
Quick try with absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/S7AGp/1/ , with the idea of using `bottom: 0;` to position the bottom of text at the bottom of the container.

It doesn't work because absolute positioning removes its content from the flow and there's nothing left in the container (e.g. you don't move an absolutely positioned element with a scrollbar afaik).

Good:
So here's a **[solution using scrollTop()](http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/S7AGp/3/)**.

Note: I used jQuery but this one should be in JS, if you don't use jQuery or another framework elsewhere in your project

Comment: I appreciate the time you spent with this answer, but I'm looking to scroll the text from the right column to the left column as described in my question. You have provided good information though an an alternative solution that might work for some people's cases.