# Scroll bar does not appears when using CSS3 Column-count

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a div of fixed width and height containing some text.

The div is styled to use css3 column as below:

```
-moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:2;
```

The text flows ok (moz. iexplore, chrome), but shows no scroll bar. (css: overflow:auto;)

If I force the scroll with  overflow:scroll; the div shows both horizontal and vertical scroll bar but no "handle" to scroll.

Any idea how to work around this problem?

Comment: [I don't see your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/mGW45/)?

Answer (score 0):

did you try only seeting the scroll to x or y?

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !actually I also found another question who  answered it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865717/multi-column-vertical-scrolling-in-css-javascript