# Scroll vertically with fixed columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiple-columns

I have a fixed-size container with dynamic content. The content is a series of items of varying heights. I want the items to flow vertically (each visually beneath the previous), but be able to inject a column break on a particular item. I use JavaScript to inject the column breaks, and thus know how many total columns are needed, and thus can inject the total column count somewhere (if helpful).

Here's what I had been using that I thought used to work in Chrome. The desire is to have A1-A5 in one column, and B1-B2 in a second column. The entire `section` should scroll vertically, not horizontally.

```css
section { width:400px; height:300px; font:9pt sans-serif; overflow:auto }
div { margin-bottom:1em; -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid }
h3 { margin:0; background:#000; color:#fff; padding:4px; font-size:9pt }
span { display:block; height:45px; background:#ddd; padding:4px }

/* The following are injected by JavaScript */
section { -webkit-column-count:2 }
#B1 { -webkit-column-break-before:always }
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="A1"><h3>A1</h3><span>content</span></div>
  <div id="A2"><h3>A2</h3><span>content</span></div>
  <div id="A3"><h3>A3</h3><span>content</span></div>
  <div id="A4"><h3>A4</h3><span>content</span></div>
  <div id="A5"><h3>A5</h3><span>content</span></div>
  <div id="B1"><h3>B1</h3><span>content</span></div>
  <div id="B2"><h3>B2</h3><span>content</span></div>
</section>
```

As seen in Chrome, the above snippet wraps A4 onto a second column and creates three columns scrolling horizontally. **How can I achieve my desire of two columns, scrolling vertically?**

<sub>It is easy for me to change the global CSS, and to apply new custom CSS to each `<div>` with JavaScript, but (for complex reasons) it is hard for me to modify the DOM using JavaScript. I'd prefer a solution that does not modify the DOM.</sub>

Comment: Too many "and thus" -es lol

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith One too many, or two too many? ;)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865717/multi-column-vertical-scrolling-in-css-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you're having it to do with defining the height of the "section" element in the first css block. Make it so:

```
section { width:400px; height:auto; font:9pt sans-serif; overflow:auto }
```

Everything should be fine with that change. [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/58dLqf9p/)

You will lose the fixed size though. I couldn't find a configuration that didn't fail this requirement.

Comment: This is possibly workable; it requires that I wrap the `<section>` in another element and put the fixed height and overflow on that one. Because this requires a change to the DOM I will defer marking this answer as accepted until/unless none other exists.

Comment: I tried a lot of tests without changing the DOM and it just appears to be acting strange. For example it adds the vertical scroll bar on "overflow-y:scroll" but still using horizontal scrolling. If you set "overflow-x:scroll" Then there is no vertical scroll bar but there is a horizontal one. It's as if it wants to do the right thing but can't figure it out.